# How to sort using NSSortDescriptor and complex logic?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nssortdescriptor

I have the following code that sorts by ascending.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"someproperty.name" ascending:YES];
    NSMutableArray   *sortedReleases = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[unsortedarray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]]];
    [sortDescriptor release];
```

What I want to do is do a sort where:

Show the ones where a sortedRelease is being followed by active current user (complex logic that goes in a function??)

This is what I need in my custom function:

```
for (Release *release in sortedReleases){

if( [[[MainController sharedMainController] activeUser] isFollowingRelease:release] ){

return NSOrderedAscending;
}

}
```

Sort the rest using acsending (how it is doing it currently)

How would I get about doing that?

I know I asked this question earlier and maybe I asked it the wrong way but that was not what i was looking for. I want to be able to sort based on a result of a function. And then alphabetically.

UPDATED CODE:

```
 NSArray *sortedReleases = [theReleases sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
        Release *left = (Release*)a;
        Release *right = (Release*)b;


        if(( [[[MainController sharedMainController] activeUser] isFollowingRelease:left] )&&([[[MainController sharedMainController] activeUser] isFollowingRelease:right])){

           //sort alphabetically ????
        }
        else if (([[[MainController sharedMainController] activeUser] isFollowingRelease:left])&&(![[[MainController sharedMainController] activeUser] isFollowingRelease:right]))
        {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        else if ((![[[MainController sharedMainController] activeUser] isFollowingRelease:left])&&([[[MainController sharedMainController] activeUser] isFollowingRelease:right]))
        {
             return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }

        return [left compare:right]; //getting a warning here about incompatible types
    }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you sort arrays using custom logic, with alphabetic sorting for tie-breaking:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    Release *left = (Release*)a;
    Release *right = (Release*)b;
    BOOL isFollowingLeft = [[[MainController sharedMainController] activeUser] isFollowingRelease:left];
    BOOL isFollowingRight = [[[MainController sharedMainController] activeUser] isFollowingRelease:right];
    if (isFollowingLeft && !isFollowingRight) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if (!isFollowingLeft && isFollowingRight) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return [left.name compare:right.name];
}];
```

Comment: Yes, it will work with iOS 4.0 or newer. Which means all hardware except the 1st generation iPhone and iPod Touch are supported, unless the user has specifically chosen not to install the free upgrade (eg: because their phone is jailbroken). The backwards compatible alternative is `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` but you're encouraged to use the new block API posted by @dasblinkenlight

Comment: Yes: according to Apple documentation, this function is `Available in iOS 4.0 and later`.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance as I am a complete newbie but I can only ask and learn. I have updated my code. The goal again is to show releases that are being followed first and the rest alphabetically. Does that look OK?

Comment: @jini You should check `isFollowingRelease` on both left and right. If the answer is the same, proceed to sorting alphabetically. If `left` is following release but `right` is not, return `ascending`; if `right` is following release but left is not, return `descending`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Please don't kill me :)    I have updated my code however was nots sure on how to sort alphabetically. I am having a really tough challenge with understanding sorts. I understand the basic ones but this is being a little difficult. I have indeed visited Apple site. I really do appreciate you helping me.

Comment: @jini You should add the name of the string property on which you would like to sort alphabetically. For example, if releases have names, use `return [left.name compare:right.name];`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ok I will do that. But what do I put in the first if block? I owe you a steak dinner.